# parser class, passing in a way to specify column changes

Tags: python, python-2.7

A bit stuck here on the way to go about this. I currently have a class which is a fairly simple parser of CSV files that encapsulates the data in its `self.data` parameter and offers methods to get the data.

```
import os
from collections import namedtuple
from app import config

class CSVReader():
  def __init__(self, csv_name):
    self.csv_name = csv_name

  def read_csv():
    with open(os.path.join(config['CSV_PATH'], self.csv_name)) as f:
      c_read = csv.DictReader(f)
      self.CSVRow = namedtuple('CSV_ENTRY', c_read.fieldnames)
      self.data = [self.CSVRow(**row) for row in c_read]

  # ...
```

The problem I am having presents when I want different data representations for different columns. Here's some sample data:

```
name       is_registered   role
'Crow'     '1'             '3'
'Not Crow' '0'             '2'
```

In this case, I want something more like this:

```
 name       is_registered   role
'Crow'      True            'bird'
'Not Crow'  False           'user'
```

For the most part, a lot will remain as a string. However, I often want to change the data types to match a more intuitive type or name. How would be the most efficient way to pass instructions on how to treat the columns in this class?

The only solution that I have really come to is by adding methods like so:

```
def column_to_boolean(self, field):
  for index, entry in enumerate(self.data):
    as_dict = entry._asdict() # namedtuples are immutable
    as_dict[field] = as_dict[field] == '1'
    self.data[index] = self.CSVRow(**as_dict)
```

then in my app, I would do something like the following:

```
my_csv = CSVReader('blah.csv')
my_csv.column_to_boolean('is_registered')
my_csv.column_to_enum('role', {'3': 'bird', '2': 'user'})
```

However, this is quite time consuming and rather annoying to do for every single column change of every single row. It seems that there must be a quicker way than to iterate [number of column changes] times (in one iteration over the data).

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You can see how pandas does it for its [read_csv method](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#io-read-csv-table), specifically with its **converters** parameter as a dictionary of functions whose keys are column names or indexes. e.g. `converters = {1: bool, 2: lambda role: role_map[role]}`

Comment: @Crow If you want to speed things up, I would not use DictReader and use simple one, this would save quite a number dictionary lookups.